# Java NIO File-System-Watcher missing Events

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, filesystemwatcher

For my home-automation project, i'm using some raspberries and java. To read the state of the GPIOs (Connection pins) i'm using the file-system-based api, which is quite simple:

```
/sys/class/gpio/gpioX/value
```

is a file, that simple contains `0` or `1` depending on the signals state. The system can be configured to fire interrupts whenever the value changes. Basically that means, a file system watcher monitoring this file for changes will be invoked upon change.

now, when working with a signal, where you want to detect both edges (rising and falling), it will become a bit tricky, depending on frequency. For fast signals, reading the file AFTER the FSW has been notified might already return a wrong value. (FSW notified on "1", and when reading the file, it is already "0")

So, I used a simple toggle-logic to determine the state, assuming that a notification ofc. always means a change in state. However, this sometimes falls out of sync, and when this happens, the log also shows 2 events super close together, leading to the assumption that a third one in between has been missed.

So, the general issue seems to be about how the event-gathering on the nio-fsw works, or at least how I implemented it:

this is the part of the code responsible to notify the actual value change listeners. It's already raised in a thread in order to be able to return to `key.reset()` asap - but still this seems to be not fast enough for high frequency signals.

At this point, I'm wondering if this is done correctly. I mean, no matter how minimal the workload between `pollEvents()` and `key.reset()` might be, in an universe full of coincidences, two events could be so close together that one of it will be missed.

If this is implemented "okay" and it is a drawback of the NIO-fsw, do other watchers, like apache-commons suffer from the same issue? (Never had any missed event with a c#-fsw)

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            // initialize the current state, so we can reliable detect state
            // changes.
            if (this.lastState == null)
                lastState = this.getState();

            WatchKey key = watchService.take();

            for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                Path path = (Path) event.context();

                //Log.d(getClass(), "Watch Event: " + event.kind() + ": " + path.toAbsolutePath());
                if (path.toString().contains("value")) {
                    if (this.edgeMode == EdgeMode.rising) {
                        lastState = SimpleGPIOState.ON;
                    } else if (this.edgeMode == EdgeMode.falling) {
                        lastState = SimpleGPIOState.OFF;
                    } else {
                        if (lastState != SimpleGPIOState.ON)
                            lastState = SimpleGPIOState.ON;
                        else if (lastState != SimpleGPIOState.OFF)
                            lastState = SimpleGPIOState.OFF;
                    }
                    
                    //notify each listener on a thread to be able to call
                    //key.reset() without waiting for processing results.
                    Thread notifier = new Thread(new Runnable(){            
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            onStateChanged(lastState);
                        }
                    });
                    
                    notifier.start();
                }
            }

            key.reset();

            if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                break;
            }
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.cf(getClass(), "Listener stopped.");
    } finally {
        if (watchService != null) {
            try {
                watchService.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        thread = null;
    }
}
```

ps.: I know there is `pi4j`, but I don't like it :P

Comment: What is `edgeMode` and where do you set its value?

Comment: @k314159 Edge Mode describes, if the system should generate listener-notifications when the signal changes from 0 -> 1 (RISING), from 1 -> 0 (FALLiNG) or any direction (BOTH). Value is set in the constructor call of the class.

Comment: That is not relevant to the question, but note that starting a thread is considered a heavy operation (at least until loom and VirtualThread becom available in a few years), and it is not recommended to create them in loops, like in your example. You should instead define a threadpool before the loop, for example by using `java.util.concurrent.Executors.CachedThreadPool`, and submit runnables to it in your loop. It should improve the loop performance / throughput. Nonetheless, I am wondering if the watch event is adapted to your use-case. Have you looked Socket channels and selectors ?

Comment: More importantly, note that a watchevent does not necessarily represent a single operation, but possibly repeated operations of the same nature. A watchevent has a count() method, to know how many operations it represents. It means that two successive write operations can be represented by a single WatchEvent of kind `MODIFY` and count() `2` . Also, one of the WatchEvent kins is `OVERFLOW`, to notify user that nio is not capable to accurately represent high frequency changes.

Comment: @amanin thx for these hints. Yeah Threadpool would be better, agree on that. Especially the hint on the `count` might be key, wasn't aware on that one. I will give it a try and see if there are WatchEvents with Count 2 generated. If so, handling them as a single operation would obviously cause my internal state to fall out of sync.

Answer (score 1):

based on amanin comments about the `count` attribute of the Watch-Event, I've now modified the code (and using a ThreadpoolExecutor) - Up to now My internal state didn't fall out of sync anymore, and there are "Multi-Count-Events" logged. The appearence is very rare, but they are there. So, obviously, threading such an `Event` as a single Event lead to problems in synchronity.

```
2022-08-26 12:12:29, es.gardencontrol.gpio.concrete.FlowMeterGPIO: Throughput: 82.22 l/min (Sum: 143.13999999999993); sps: 370 , pulses: 201371
2022-08-26 12:12:30, es.gardencontrol.gpio.concrete.FlowMeterGPIO: Throughput: 83.56 l/min (Sum: 144.52999999999992); sps: 376 , pulses: 201747
2022-08-26 12:12:30, es.gardencontrol.gpio.concrete.FlowMeterGPIO: Multi-Count-Event spotted.
2022-08-26 12:12:31, es.gardencontrol.gpio.concrete.FlowMeterGPIO: Throughput: 83.33 l/min (Sum: 145.9199999999999); sps: 375 , pulses: 202122
2022-08-26 12:12:32, es.gardencontrol.gpio.concrete.FlowMeterGPIO: Throughput: 84.44 l/min (Sum: 147.3299999999999); sps: 380 , pulses: 202502
```

snip:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    try {
        while (true) {
            
            // initialize the current state, so we can reliable detect state
            // changes.
            if (this.lastState == null)
                lastState = this.getState();

            WatchKey key = watchService.take();

            for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {
                if (event.count() > 1){
                    Log.cf(getClass(), "Multi-Count-Event spotted.");
                }
                
                for (int i = 0; i < event.count(); i++){
                    Path path = (Path) event.context();

                    //Log.d(getClass(), "Watch Event: " + event.kind() + ": " + path.toAbsolutePath());
                    if (path.toString().contains("value")) {
                        if (this.edgeMode == EdgeMode.rising) {
                            lastState = SimpleGPIOState.ON;
                        } else if (this.edgeMode == EdgeMode.falling) {
                            lastState = SimpleGPIOState.OFF;
                        } else {
                            if (lastState != SimpleGPIOState.ON)
                                lastState = SimpleGPIOState.ON;
                            else if (lastState != SimpleGPIOState.OFF)
                                lastState = SimpleGPIOState.OFF;
                        }
                        
                        //notify each listener on a thread to be able to call
                        //key.reset() without waiting for processing results.
                        executorService.submit(() -> {
                            onStateChanged(SimpleGPIOState.valueOf(lastState.toString()));
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

            key.reset();

            if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                break;
            }
        }

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.cf(getClass(), "Listener stopped.");
    } finally {
        if (executorService != null)
            executorService.shutdown();
        
        if (watchService != null) {
            try {
                watchService.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        thread = null;
    }
}
```

Update: replaced the listener-parameter to use a fresh copy of the `lastState` variable, as this might lead to concurrency issues otherwise:

```
onStateChanged(SimpleGPIOState.valueOf(lastState.toString()));
```